# junit test case with null object

Tags: testing, junit, nullpointerexception, null

I want to write Person class with 3 parameter constructor and if user give null string for name and surname for a person, I want to return null for that object because I want to use junit assertNull function to show that object is not created with null string.

```
public Person(String names,String surnames,int ages)
{
    if(!names.equals(null) && !surnames.equals(null))
    {
        name = names;
        surname = surnames;
    }
    else
    {
        return;
    }

    if(ages > 0)
        age = ages;
    else
        return;
}
```

and test is like that

```
    @Test
public void createPerson()
{
    String ad = null;
    String soyad = null;
    int age = 10;
    Person p = new Person(ad, soyad, age);
    assertNull("Object is not created!", p );
}
```

how can do it I get null pointer exception?

Comment: No way to return null from a constructor

Answer (score 1):

You get a NullPointerException because you are calling the equals method on a null object. If you want to check whether a String is not null, you need to use `someString != null`.

What you need to do is:

```
if (names != null && surnames != null)
```

But that does not solve your problem that it is not possible to return null from a constructor. The only thing you could do ist to throw a NullPointerException—and that is exactly what your code does. There must be some other way to solve the problem you have.

Comment: thank you for your comments I missunderstood the testing concept. It is correct thing the get errors with null parameters for constructor.